# How can I share a Windows 7 folder to lucid32 running in vagrant

Tags: vagrant

I am using vagrant to run a lucid32 install. I have installed LAMP and got that working. What do I need to do in order to mount a windows share on the host machine inside the lucid32 install?

I tried adding A windows path to the vagrant file but get:

C:/Users/myuser/Sites/Vagrantfile:37: invalid Unicode escape
config.vm.share_folder "vagwin","/windows", "c:\users\lukem\Sites"

Comment: Could you put the full line, the documentation is not clear about how to put addionnal parameters. "Additional options may be passed in as an options hash for a 4th parameter"

Comment: Man, you got a bad case of the vagwins. Terrible disease : (

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to double-escape the slashes, atleast I had to on Windows 7, ie, each \ should be \\

Answer (score 13):

You can also use forward slashes to avoid having to escape the backslashes.

```
 config.vm.synced_folder "c:/Users/david", "/home/david"
```

will map your Windows home directory to your home directory on the VM (assuming your name is david).

Comment: this looks much nicer than escaping a backslash

Answer (score 2):

This is really a ruby question because your Vagrantfile is actually ruby. Double quoted strings are interpolated in ruby and the backslash in some cases is a metacharacter. Change your

```
"c:\users\lukem\Sites"
```

to

```
'c:\users\lukem\Sites'
```

If you try something like this in irb (the ruby repl), it looks like this:

```
> x = "c:\users\lukem\Sites"
=> "c:\users\lukemSites"
> x = 'c:\users\lukem\Sites'
=> "c:\\users\\lukem\\Sites"
```

At least, this is how it works in irb on my mac. I didn't have a windows box to test it on.

Semi-interesting sidebar... if you ever switch to vagrant 2 and are using synched_folder, the order of host-to-guest is reversed:

http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/basic_usage.html

http://docs-v1.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/config/vm/share_folder.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape like this `C:\\users\\lukem\\Sites`

Comment: Please, use the code format in your answer as it is misleading right now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using double quote you need this syntax to escape it

```
"C:\\users\\lukem\\Sites"
```

or

```
"C:/users/lukem/Sites"
```

If you are using single quote you do not need to escape it.

Remember to run `vagrant reload` after you update your **Vagrantfile**